# How much time passes during Trainspotting?

Tags: trainspotting

In the film version of "Trainspotting" how much time elapses from the beginning of the film, the 5-a-side match, and Renton walking away into the distance? I don't know if the book itself follows a precise chronology and the film doesn't do flashback/forwards but have no clue of the time span from start to finish.